# Jenkins + Docker: How to control docker user when using Image.inside command

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I am trying to setup a Jenkins CI pipeline using docker images as containers for my build processes. I am defining a Jenkinsfile to have a build pipeline as code. I am doing something like this:

```
node {
  docker.withRegistry('http://my.registry.com', 'docker-credentials') {     
      def buildimage = docker.image('buildimage:latest');
      buildimage.pull();
      buildimage.inside("")
      {
        stage('Checkout sources') {
          git url: '...', credentialsId: '...'
        }

        stage('Run Build and Publish') {
            sh "..."
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I am stumbling upon a weird behavior of the Docker pipeline plugin. In the build output I can see that the Image.inside(...) command triggers the container with a

```
docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 ...
```

This makes my build fail, because the user defined in the Dockerfile does not have the UID 1000 ... another user is actually taken. I even tried specifying which user should be used within the Jenkinsfile

```
node {
  docker.withRegistry('http://my.registry.com', 'docker-credentials') {     
      def buildimage = docker.image('buildimage:latest');
      buildimage.pull();
      buildimage.inside("-u otheruser:othergroup")
      {
        stage('Checkout sources') {
          git url: '...', credentialsId: '...'
        }

        stage('Run Build and Publish') {
            sh "..."
        }
      }
  }
}
```

but this leads to a duplicate -u switch in the resulting docker run command

```
docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -u otheruser:othergroup ...
```

and obviously only the first -u is applied because my build still fails. I also did debugging using whoami to validate my assumptions.

So my questions: how can I change this behavior? Is there a switch where I can turn the -u 1000:1000 off? Is this even a bug? I actually like to work with the Docker plugin because it simplifies the usage of an own docker registry with credentials maintained in Jenkins. However, is there another simple way to get to my goal if the Docker Plugin is not usable?

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/docker-workflow-1.9/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/WithContainerStep.java#L175) or [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/docker-workflow-1.9/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/client/DockerClient.java#L278) is hardcoded the fact of append the uid and gid of the user that is running Jenkins (in your case, the Jenkins user created inside the oficial docker image).

You can change the user that runs the processes inside your Jenkins image passing the --user (or -u) argument to the `docker run` command. Maybe this can minimize your problems.

**Edited**

> how can I change this behavior? Is there a switch where I can turn the -u 1000:1000 off?

You can't change this behaviour in the actual version because the whoami is hardcoded.

> Is this even a bug?

In [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/57) pull request seems that they are working on it.

> However, is there another simple way to get to my goal if the Docker Plugin is not usable?

The new pipeline plugin version that comes with Jenkins also use the docker-workflow-plugin to run the containers. I don't know another plugin to run that in a simple way. To workaround this, you can run your Jenkins as root but is a very ugly solution.

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my Question. The hint on running using -u is not helpful as it does not work as also stated in the question.

Comment: I think to answer your question, make sure your Dockerfile creates a user in the container with a UID and GID that matches the jenkins user (or some other non-privileged user) that will eventually run the pipeline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958484/how-to-dynamically-add-jenkins-user-and-permissions-inside-docker-container

Answer (score 58):

I found you can actually change user by adding `args` like following. Although -u 1000:1000 will still be there in the `docker run`, you will an additional -u [your user] after 1000:1000. Docker will acutally use latest -u parameter

```
agent {
  docker {
    image 'your image'
    args '-u root --privileged'
  }
}
```

Comment: This code it's correct, but @z0beat 's answer is right too, helped me a lot

Comment: running `docker start -u 1:1 -u 2:2 ...` sets user 2 when executed locally. But when started with Jenkins it does not seem to work. Why?

Comment: I have the same issue as @Datz I set the user with -u but then nothing is executed -u root works tho

Comment: I had this issue and solved it by using `my_image.inside('-u root:root')` and then in my `sh` commands I switch to the user that I need to run the commands (i.e. 'su - my_user')