# Jenkins pipeline alpine agent "apk update ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied"

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, alpine-linux

I'm using Alpine docker image as a Jenkins pipeline agent but I keep getting permission denied error while running  `apk update` or `apk add package`. I seeing similar error for Ubuntu images also while running `apt update` or `apt install`

Here's my Jenkinsfile:

```js
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Initialization') {
            agent any
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        stage('Git Clone') {
            agent { docker { image 'alpine:3.12.0' } }
            steps {
                sh '''
                    apk update;
                    apk add --no-cache git;
                    apk add --no-cache openssh;
                    git -v;
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the Jenkins output:

```js
+ docker inspect -f . alpine:3.12.0
WARNING: Error loading config file: /root/.docker/config.json: stat /root/.docker/config.json: permission denied
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 1001:0 -w "/opt/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Deploy Glosfy Frontend" -v "/opt/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Deploy Glosfy Frontend:/opt/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Deploy Glosfy Frontend:rw,z" -v "/opt/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Deploy Glosfy Frontend@tmp:/opt/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Deploy Glosfy Frontend@tmp:rw,z" -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** alpine:3.12.0 cat
$ docker top 166c9ace17a4eb6aef0af0bbc04902ee4a358212be7f029550fb39a921e305aa -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ apk update
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 166c9ace17a4eb6aef0af0bbc04902ee4a358212be7f029550fb39a921e305aa
$ docker rm -f 166c9ace17a4eb6aef0af0bbc04902ee4a358212be7f029550fb39a921e305aa
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 99
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can someone help me figure out the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please modify the docker tag from Jenkins pipeline like this:

```
docker { 
image 'alpine:3.12.0' 
args '-u root:root'
 }
```

Comment: The Jenkins is running standalone in a VPS, not in a container. Just the agents are docker containers. Do the volume permissions still matter ?

Comment: Try add this to your docker tag from Jenkins Pipeline:
docker {
   image 'alpine:3.12.0' 
    args '-u root:root' }

Comment: adding the args to change the user to root worked like a charm, thanks much. I didn't know that we could pass in args in pipeline like this. Thanks again.

Comment: I can accept the answer if you update it with the details from the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that Jenkins is running the container with a non-root user, hence the `Permission denied` error.

Try changing your pipeline like so:

```
agent {
    docker {
            image 'alpine:3.12.0'
            args '-u root'
        }
    }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51986870/12155142).