# "EACCES: permission denied" when running npm install by jenkins and using docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm

i've created a simple nodejs project containing a Jenkinsfile with this content:

```
pipeline {
  agent { docker { image 'node:12-alpine' } }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm install'
      }
    }
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm run test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

jenkins service is running by its own user named "jenkins", i've added that user to docker user group due to previous permission issues (permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon) and i already have docker plugin installed in jenkins.

but when i run the build job, i get the following error and the build fails

```
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'
```

if i use

```
agent any
```

in the Jenkinsfile, i don't get the mentioned error. but i want to use docker agents.

why is this happening? am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user can't write in the default cache directory, you can overwrite it using this environment variable at the beginning of your pipeline :

```
environment {
    NPM_CONFIG_CACHE = "${WORKSPACE}/.npm"
}
```

Comment: that worked, thank you. i recently found out that jenkins automatically sets user of container to the user running jenkins by -u option of docker run command and because of that, the user doesn't have write access to anywhere out of workspace.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to `args '-u root:root'` to the docker tag as per this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330483/2155645