# How to dynamically add Jenkins user and permissions inside Docker container

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I am building a declarative Jenkins pipeline for my python project, I get the following error message when using Pip.

```
WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user.
```

My **Jenkinsfile**:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'python:3.7.5'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build Dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh "pip install -r requirements.txt"
            }
        }
}
    post {
        always {
            sh "Job finished"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a new defined user in the Docker container instead of using the `root` user. You have to  create the new user with the outerscope [GID and UID](https://medium.com/@gggauravgandhi/uid-user-identifier-and-gid-group-identifier-in-linux-121ea68bf510) references of the `jenkins` user on your Jenkins server. To read more about GID and UID inside Docker I recommend you to read [this interesting article](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf).

Let's use a Dockerfile agent instead of a remote image, so we can dynamically assign the needed variables as build arguments.

First we are going to fetch the outerscope GID, UID and username of the jenkins account:

**Jenkinsfile**:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {

    environment {
            JENKINS_USER_NAME = "${sh(script:'id -un', returnStdout: true).trim()}"
            JENKINS_USER_ID = "${sh(script:'id -u', returnStdout: true).trim()}"
            JENKINS_GROUP_ID = "${sh(script:'id -g', returnStdout: true).trim()}"
    }
}
```

We now have assigned the GID, UID and username to various environment variables for the scope of the pipeline. We can now assign them as build arguments for our Dockerfile.

**Jenkinsfile**:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {

    environment {
            JENKINS_USER_NAME = "${sh(script:'id -un', returnStdout: true).trim()}"
            JENKINS_USER_ID = "${sh(script:'id -u', returnStdout: true).trim()}"
            JENKINS_GROUP_ID = "${sh(script:'id -g', returnStdout: true).trim()}"
    }
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile.build'
            additionalBuildArgs '''\
            --build-arg GID=$JENKINS_GROUP_ID \
            --build-arg UID=$JENKINS_USER_ID \
            --build-arg UNAME=$JENKINS_USER_NAME \
            '''
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build Dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh "pip install -r requirements.txt"
            }
        }
}
    post {
        always {
            sh "Job finished"
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in the Dockerfile we have to create the defined user:

**Dockerfile.build**

```
FROM python:3.8.3

ARG GID
ARG UID
ARG UNAME

ENV GROUP_ID=$GID
ENV USER_ID=$UID
ENV USERNAME=$UNAME

RUN mkdir /home/$USERNAME

RUN groupadd -g $GROUP_ID $USERNAME
RUN useradd -r -u $USER_ID -g $USERNAME -d /home/$USERNAME $USERNAME
RUN chown $USERNAME:$USERNAME /home/$USERNAME

USER $USERNAME
WORKDIR /home/$USERNAME

RUN python -m venv testpipe_venv

CMD ["/bin/bash -c 'source testpipe_venv/bin/activate'"]
```

Note that we have to create a virtual python environment as we are not the `root` user anymore. In the final command we activate the virtual environmnet for usage in the pipeline.

Comment: I had to follow the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805076/setting-build-args-for-dockerfile-agent-using-a-jenkins-declarative-pipeline for the GID and UID to actually be set correctly.